# javascript sort array to align with order array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Here is an example:

```
            //    0     1       2      3       4
 var people = ['jack','jill','nancy','tom','cartman'];
 var order  = [3,1,4,0,2];

 // somehow sort people array to the order specified in the order array

          //  3      1       4        0      2
 people == ['tom','jill','cartman','jack','nancy'];
```

I have used .sort with a function before, but am still at a loss on this one.

**UPDATE**

after seeing some answers, I can't believe this was not obvious to me. So as there are many ways to do this, winner will be determined by jsperf.

(also I am upvoting everyone with a working answer)

**The RACE! http://jsperf.com/array-sorted-to-order-array3**

Comment: Winner should be determined by readability and clearest of intent first :)

Comment: Winner by performance doesn't make any sense

Comment: Do you actually need to sort the existing Array? Many answers here are replacing the Array instead, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: replace or produce a sorted result is equally functional. And I disagree, about scoring. The best performing method is the right way to do it, sorry.

Comment: @Fresheyeball If you're doing a game, emulator or have a similar high performance requirement in JavaScript, otherwise it generally isn't the *right way*.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: You mean it's equally functional in your situation. It isn't in all situations.

Comment: @user1689607 I am interested, can you describe a situation in which its not? Can't you just set the origin array to the result array?

Comment: @alex performance is part of the user experience. UX > Readability 99% of the time.

Comment: @Fresheyeball Depends on what else is pointing to that original array.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: If you replace the Array referenced by the `people` variable, you're only updating that one reference. If there are other references to the original Array, they won't automatically be updated to reference the new Array, so your references will be out of sync. All depends on what's needed.

Comment: I did not think of the pointer situation. Good point.

Comment: Forgive me SO peoples, my whole stradegy turned out to be wrong. I have asked a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149426/sort-dom-elements-to-order-array-with-jquery for those who still want to save my tired butt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order` is an array of indicies. So just iterate through that, pulling out the values you want in the order spcified, making a new array.

```
var people = ['jack','jill','nancy','tom','cartman'];
var order  = [3,1,4,0,2];

var sorted = [];
for (var i = 0; i < order.length; i++) {
  var desiredIndex = order[i];
  sorted.push(people[desiredIndex]);
}

console.log(sorted);
// ["tom", "jill", "cartman", "jack", "nancy"]
```

Sometimes sorting isn't "sorting". Sometimes you just need to make a new thing by pulling data from your other things.

Comment: @Fresheyeball I don't think it's odd. Dropping back to basic constructs such as a `for` loop is generally fastest.

Comment: @alex it shouldn't be though. With all the hype surrounding map and reduce, I thought the browser had a way of optimizing this kind of operation far beyond the basic construct.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: It's mostly just that those functional approaches provide nice clean code. The functions can also be stored and reused for different situations. But functions require some overhead to invoke, so a traditional `for` loop is the way to go when speed is a high priority.

Comment: Functionless iteration is usually fastest. Even if it is more verbose.

Answer (score 6):

```
sorted = []
order.forEach(function(i) { sorted.push(people[i]) });
```

or, more fancy but less readable (IMO):

```
sorted = order.reduce(function(r, i) { 
    return r.concat([people[i]])
}, []);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just another way :)

```
people = order.map(function(value) { return people[value]; });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pThsg/).

Comment: `.map()` is the *only* way to do this IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I dunno, something like this perhaps?

```
var people = ['jack','jill','nancy','tom','cartman'];
var order  = [3,1,4,0,2];


var result = [], i, n=order.length;

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  result[ order[i] ] = people[i];
}
```