# Sort DOM elements to order array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

A moment ago I asked this question:
[javascript sort array to align with order array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148941/javascript-sort-array-to-align-with-order-array/13148972) based on what turned out to be a false premise. (I've been up for too long, give me a break please).

What I really need to do is sort DOM elements. **Performance is key** in my application as it will be running in very CPU-poor situations. So what I have is something like this:

```
<div id="moduleWrap">
    <div class="module">Jack</div>    <!-- 0 -->
    <div class="module">Jill</div>    <!-- 1 -->
    <div class="module">Nancy</div>   <!-- 2 -->
    <div class="module">Tom</div>     <!-- 3 -->
    <div class="module">Cartman</div> <!-- 4 -->
</div>
```

And in JavaScript:

```
$modules = $('#moduleWrap .module');
order    = [3,1,4,0,2];
```

What I need is this:

```
<div id="moduleWrap">
    <div class="module">Tom</div>     <!-- 3 -->
    <div class="module">Jill</div>    <!-- 1 -->
    <div class="module">Cartman</div> <!-- 4 -->
    <div class="module">Jack</div>    <!-- 0 -->
    <div class="module">Nancy</div>   <!-- 2 -->
</div>
```

I thought (wrongly) that I could sort the jQuery object and simply append the result. This is not so.

Comment: If you really care about performance that much why do you use jquery in the first place?

Comment: Another part of the application is using highcharts, which needs it (actually I am using Zepto). And rather than serving different js files to different views, I am leveraging the browser caching by bundling js into a single file. Jquery is not needed here necessarily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would just iterate over the `order` array and rearrange the DOM elements accordingly:

```
var elements = [];
$.each(order, function(i, position) {
    elements.push($modules.get(position));
});

$('#moduleWrap').append(elements);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HHvsv/)

To increase performance, you can take away more and more jQuery. For example:

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById('moduleWrap');
for(var i = 0, l = order.length; i < l; i++) {
    wrapper.appendChild($modules.get(order[i]));
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HHvsv/1/)

jQuery is great because it makes things easy, but if you need high performance, you should rather go without it.

Comment: I don't believe you can append an array of Dom elements. Also it can't be in addition to in the Dom. It must replace. Pure js answers acceptable.

Comment: @Fresheyeball: Yes you can pass an array of elements (see the docs) and why can't you append (add) elements? If the element already exist in the DOM, it is moved to the new location, not cloned. This is a very easy way to rearrange DOM elements.

Comment: As far as. Can tell you can append elements, but not an array. Great answer btw.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late, but maybe it will help someone. I was trying to do a similar thing and #Felix Kling's answer got me 90% there. But in my case I have a div id which is equal to the order values, like this:

```
order    = [3,1,4,0,2];

<div id="0" class="module">Jack</div>    <!-- 0 -->
<div id="1" class="module">Jill</div>    <!-- 1 -->
<div id="2" class="module">Nancy</div>   <!-- 2 -->
<div id="3" class="module">Tom</div>     <!-- 3 -->
<div id="4" class="module">Cartman</div> <!-- 4 -->
```

then I can simply push the element using the position value

```
var elements = [];
$.each(order, function(i, position) {
    elements.push($('#'+position));
});

$('#moduleWrap').append(elements);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Detaching the elements from the DOM tree may speed up the process.

```
$modules.detach();

var len = order.length,
    temp = [];

for( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
  temp.push( $modules[ order[i] ] );
}

$("#moduleWrap").append( temp );
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/rEFu3/
​