# How to change the div order while making it responsive?

Tags: jquery

I am working on a responsive website for which I want to change the html div order while making it responsive. Is there any way to change the html order after resizing the browser size? insertBefore, insertAfter and .replaceWith() is not useful in this case.

Desktop html

```
<div class="list-wrapper">
    <div class="col c1">column 1</div>
    <div class="col c2">column 2</div>
    <div class="col c3">column 3</div>
    <div class="col c4">column 4</div>
    <div class="col c5">column 5</div>
</div>
```

Responsive html

```
<div class="list-wrapper">
    <div class="col c1">column 1</div>
    <div class="col c5">column 5</div>
    <div class="col c2">column 2</div>   
    <div class="col c3">column 3</div>
    <div class="col c4">column 4</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149426/sort-dom-elements-to-order-array-with-jquery ?

Comment: Thanks a lot maximkou. I have changed few things from the answer of the possible duplicate question. Posting my answer below. This was my first question in stack overflow. I was trying since last few days by own. But after posting the question here, I go the answer in few hours. stackoverflow.com ROCKS!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Posting below the working html.

  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
    .list-wrapper { float:left; width:100%; border:1px solid #000}
    .list-wrapper .col {float:left; border:1px solid #f00; width:18%;}

    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

    var $modules = $('.list-wrapper .col');
    var order    = [1,3,4,0,2];

    var elements = [];
    $.each(order, function(i, position) {
        elements.push($modules.get(position));
    });

    $('.list-wrapper').html(elements); 
    });

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="list-wrapper">
        <div class="col c1">column 1</div>
        <div class="col c2">column 2</div>
        <div class="col c3">column 3</div>
        <div class="col c4">column 4</div>
        <div class="col c5">column 5</div>
    </div>


    <div class="list-wrapper">
        <div class="col c1">column 1</div>
        <div class="col c2">column 2</div>
        <div class="col c3">column 3</div>
        <div class="col c4">column 4</div>
        <div class="col c5">column 5</div>
    </div>

    <div class="list-wrapper">
        <div class="col c1">column 1</div>
        <div class="col c2">column 2</div>
        <div class="col c3">column 3</div>
        <div class="col c4">column 4</div>
        <div class="col c5">column 5</div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.resize()` method: [JQUERY](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

```
$( window ).resize(function() {

    console.log( 'Handler for .resize() called.' );
    var newC2 = $( ".col c2" ).replaceWith( $(".col c5") );
    var newC3 = $( ".col c3" ).replaceWith( newC2 );
    var newC4 = $( ".col c4" ).replaceWith( newC3 );
    $( ".col c5" ).replaceWith( newC4 );

});
```

Comment: Hi Manolo, thanks for your reply. I can write window.resize, but the main problem is re-ordering the html.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that for modern browsers you could accomplish this with just CSS (*[using flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)*)

```
.list-wrapper{display:flex;flex-direction:column}

.c1{order:1}
.c2{order:3}
.c3{order:4}
.c4{order:5}
.c5{order:2}
```

(*you will need to use vendor prefixes to make it work for all browsers*)
**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/Xdn2G/2/