# Can I use jQuery to get children NOT in the order they are in the document, but after moving them?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="myDiv1"></div>
  <div class="myDiv2"></div>
  <div class="myDiv3"></div>
</div>
```

I'm using `$(".container").children()` to get all the "myDiv"s, then animating them to reorder them based on their top value. Such as

> $(child).animate({ 'top': xx}, {duration: 1000});

which would re-order them to something like this(it could always be different):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="myDiv2"></div>
  <div class="myDiv3"></div>
  <div class="myDiv1"></div>
</div>
```

When I call `$(".container").children()` again, they are being returned in the order [myDiv1, myDiv2, myDiv3], NOT in the order they appear in after I've switched them around, [myDiv2, myDiv3, myDiv1].

Is there something I can use to get them in their new order? Not the document order?

Comment: You need to delegate the event -- when the DOM changes, or is added to or removed, jQuery doesn't know.

Comment: can't you use a js array to save their order?

Comment: @SterlingArcher I don't see how this is related to delegate. The OP asks how the code needs to be changed so that a second call (after the animation) of `$(".container").children()` reflects the new order of the elements.

Comment: After the animation finished you should reorder the elements in the DOM too. [Sort DOM elements to order array with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149426) at least if you want that it is also syntactically correct and not only visually.

Answer (score 0):

You know the `top` is changing, so could you simply sort the elements you get back from the selector based on their current position? Here's an example:

```js
$(function() {
  var divs = $('.container').children();
  
  divs.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).offset().top < $(b).offset().top ? 1 : -1;
  });
  
  console.log(divs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="myDiv3"></div>
  <div class="myDiv1"></div>
  <div class="myDiv2"></div>
</div>
```